# How do you change the size of of an image when you push a button in Objective C - xcode?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, image, size

I am trying to change the size of an image when a button is pushed to make it get longer or shorter. I would prefer it if it could be animated into changing its size, but without animation would also help, if anyone can give me any information if this is possible, and how then it would be appreciated

Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: The easiest way to do this is to use Core Animation, but the code will be different depending on whether you are coding for iOS or for Mac OS X.  What's your target platform?

Comment: @KristopherJohnson it is for IOS, I am quite new to this, how would I do this with Core Animation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using a `UIImageView` then you simply change the size (this may cause bad effects depending on how much you stretch etc).

**NOTE:** `newFrame` is whatever your new frame will be

```
- (void)buttonTapped:(id)sender
{
    CGRect newFrame = ...;
    self.myImageView.frame = newFrame;
}
```

To animate it stick this inside an animation block

```
- (void)buttonTapped:(id)sender
{
    CGRect newFrame = ...;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25f 
                     animations:^{
                        self.myImageView.frame = newFrame;
                     }];
}
```